# Error next 13, typescript with fetching data inside async component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript, next.js13

[HERE ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gCb.png)

```
export const Filter = async (): Promise<JSX.Element> => {
  const { data: categories } = await api.get('/categories/')

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full relative'>
      <Container className='sticky top-[6rem] max-lg:col-span-2'>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 max-h-[40rem] overflow-y-scroll overflow-hidden'>

           
         There is the problem i think
          <Container className='flex items-center flex-col'>
            <SmallHeading>Kategoria</SmallHeading>
            <ul className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 max-h-[25rem] overflow-y-scroll overflow-hidden w-full'>
              {categories.map(c => {
                return <CategoryItem key={c.id} href={c.name} name={c.name} image={c.img} isSmall={true} />
              })}
            </ul>
          </Container>
           


        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

'Filter' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Help i'll try everythink

I tried what is in the code I gave above, I don't understand why such an error appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use async components only in `app` directory. From the [next13 docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching)

> This new data fetching model is currently being developed by the React
> team. We recommend reading the support for promises React RFC which
> introduces async/await in Server Components and a new use() hook for
> client components. While you can try it out, it is not yet stable.
> We'll keep these docs updated to reflect the latest developments.
>
> Warning: You can use async/await in layouts and pages, which are
> Server Components. Using async/await inside other components, with
> TypeScript, can cause errors from the response type from JSX. We are
> working with the TypeScript team to resolve this upstream. As a
> temporary workaround, you can use {/* @ts-expect-error Server
> Component */} to disable type checking for the component.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me, who did not know `"use client"` also prevent fetch components.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue removing "use client" from the component solved the issue.
so, don't use use async await in a client component in Next.js